# Is this a bug or is there an error in my code?

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios6

Whenever I run my app into a 'iPhone 6.0 Simulator', I get this weird behavior. The first time, it will successfully run but the 2nd time, it will crash with the error:

```
loaded the "IouView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

This is reproducible and every other time, it would work and vice versa, it would crash. Here is my app structure:

In AppDelegate:

```
self.iouViewController = [[IouViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IouView" bundle:nil];
    [iouViewController setIouTableArray:iouTableArray];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.iouViewController];
    [window setRootViewController:navController];
```

Then, in IouViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *iouTableView;
```

Up until today, I have always coded my views (tableView, etc..) programmatically. With iPhone 5 having 4" screen, I decided to stop fighting Apple and use IB along with 'Auto Layout' feature.

In my IouView.xib, this is the structure:

```
Objects: 'View', 
  Referencing Outlets: view - File's Owner

Objects: 'View'->'Table View'
  Outlets: dataSource - File's Owner
  Outlets: delegate - File's Owner
  Referencing Outlets: iouTableView - File's Owner
```

There is actually another Table View within the View but I did not include it here. Please help as I am at a lost on how to proceed! Thank you so much.

Just throwing it out there since I may not be initialize my view controllers correctly, I commented out 'loadView' and use this as init:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}
```

PS: I am building on iOS 6 SDK with Apple LLVM 4.1 and ARC enabled.

Update: Image from IB added:
[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]

Still at a lost, if you need any more code, please let me know. I created a new project with a simple navigation controller and it works for that new project but not mine. The crash is with the simulator.

Comment: If I understand correctly your IOView and view outlets are set to the same object? What happens if you use self.view exclusively. Disconnect And remove the outlet, and change all refs in your code to self.view. May be worth it as an experiment.

Comment: well, actually, in my original implementation, i don't have IouView. I only have the xib view reference the file's owner but since it crashed, i added IouView by ctrl-click the view to the source file (.m file). It turns out that without IouView, it will run and crash, cyclically. There is some serious issue here that I am missing

Comment: You don't by any chance have another class called IouViewController that could be getting loaded, do you? I've seen similar things happen with name collisions in frameworks. But this is really strange. Nothing is jumping out at me as wrong.

Comment: Hi Carl. Nope. I double check my files and nothing like IouViewController. This bug is really bugging me especially since it works once and not, etc...

Comment: Hi Carl. I got it fixed. See my answer. I am not sure if another IouView.xib did end up messing everything but I have to change that code in main.m to get it everything working. Thaks so much for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution that does not crash the simulator anymore I think. I only got through the first view. This is the 'thing' I did. If someone have insights, let them share and hopefully will help others out as well. Special thanks to Carl Veazey for helping.

What I forgot to mention was that this code was done back in the days of iOS4 without ARC. When I switch, there were a lot of changes.

Following Carl's suggestions, I took a look at 'Build Phases' -> 'Compile Sources' and saw to IouView.xib. So, I delete one. I ran the program and it shows a black screen. Finally, I looked at main.m

Original:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    return retVal;
}
```

and change it to:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([IouApp2AppDelegate class]));
}
```

and i have to #import my AppDelegate. After making that change, I can run the program multiple times and it did not crash.

Comment: That's interesting, so was it loading a different application delegate each time? How did that lead the issue you saw?

Comment: Well, there was an old xib called 'IouView.xib' that was under an archieve folder and maybe that xib was working with the old main.c code or something. I think it is loading the same AppDelegate each time since I use breakpoint and debug through it. Well, I created a brand new xcode empty project and manually create a uinavigation controller, etc..and see what is different...took a long time, very painful lol. was thinking of using diff but too many properties file would clutter it up...